# Should I call pjsua_call_make_call (pj::Call::makeCall) in a background thread?

Tags: pjsip

I am developing a multi-account SIP softphone with custom media transport. I need to manage multiple calls simultaneously. I have read in "PJSUA2 Book" ([3 PJSUA2-High Level API / General concepts / Asynchronous Operations](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#asynchronous-operations)):

> (...) all operations that involve sending and receiving SIP messages are asynchronous, meaning
> that the function that invokes the operation will complete immediately
> (...) When this function [pj::Call::makeCall] returns successfully, it does not mean that the
> call has been established, but rather it means that the call has been initiated successfully.
> You will be given the report of the call progress and/or completion in the onCallState()
> callback method of Call class.

So I thought that I could call `pj::Call::makeCall` whenever/wherever I needed to initiate a call, the function would return nearly immediately and any progress would be reported in the callback methods. But today in my test environment I noticed a few seconds delay between the moment I called the function and it returned. Below there are detailed PJSIP logs that appear between `makeCall` is called and it returned. One can see almost 4s gap before "RTP socket reachable":

```
12:08:32.727           pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:11@10.0.0.21:5060
12:08:32.727      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  .UAC dialog created
12:08:32.727      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  ..Session count inc to 2 by mod-pjsua
12:08:32.727          pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
12:08:36.069          pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 10.0.0.100:4000
12:08:36.069          pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 10.0.0.100:4001
12:08:36.069     srtp0x7f3a540052d0  ..SRTP keying SDES created
12:08:36.069          pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
12:08:36.069          pjsua_media.c  ..Call 0: media transport initialization complete: Success
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  ..Session count dec to 2 by mod-pjsua
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  .Module mod-invite added as dialog usage, data=0x7f3a5400d408
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  ..Session count inc to 4 by mod-invite
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  .Module mod-100rel added as dialog usage, data=0x7f3a5400f0a8
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  .100rel module attached
12:08:36.069      inv0x7f3a54002f08  .UAC invite session created for dialog dlg0x7f3a54002f08
12:08:36.069               endpoint  .Request msg INVITE/cseq=7778 (tdta0x7f3a5400f308) created.
12:08:36.069      inv0x7f3a54002f08  ..Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=7778 (tdta0x7f3a5400f308)
12:08:36.069      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=7778 (tdta0x7f3a5400f308)
12:08:36.069      tsx0x7f3a54012278  ....Transaction created for Request msg INVITE/cseq=7777 (tdta0x7f3a5400f308)
12:08:36.069      tsx0x7f3a54012278  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=7777 (tdta0x7f3a5400f308) in state Null
12:08:36.069          sip_resolve.c  ....Target '10.0.0.21:5060' type=Unspecified resolved to '10.0.0.21:5060' type=UDP (UDP transport)
12:08:36.069      tsx0x7f3a54012278  ....State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
12:08:36.070      dlg0x7f3a54002f08  .....Transaction tsx0x7f3a54012278 state changed to Calling
12:08:36.070            pjsua_acc.c !Sending 2 bytes keep-alive packet for acc 0 to 10.0.0.21:5060
12:08:36.070     tdta0x7f3a44005248  Destroying txdata raw
12:08:36.070            pjsua_acc.c  Sending 2 bytes keep-alive packet for acc 1 to 10.0.0.21:5060
12:08:36.070     tdta0x7f3a44005248  Destroying txdata raw
```

Is it normal? I mean, should I redesign the application and call `makeCall` in a background thread? Or is it a result of some misconfiguration? Or a bug (somewhere)?

When I compare the PJSIP logs with timestamped Wireshark output it seems to me that indeed no SIP packets are sent to PBX before `makeCall` returns. So these few seconds seem to be wasted on internal PJSIP work. Could it be an effect of some (temporary) deadlock?

The application runs on 64-bit Linux (Fedora 31 Workstation in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even more research I can reply to my own question. Maybe it could help someone...

I discovered `makeCall` triggered two DNS queries for localhost which failed after nearly 2 second each. That would make nearly 4 second gap.

The solution is to disable localhost IP address resolution completely by adding
`#define PJ_GETHOSTIP_DISABLE_LOCAL_RESOLUTION 1` into the `pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h` configuration file and recompile the PJSIP library.

The issue turned out to be already known and has been resolved in case of iOS: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1342

There was somebody else who experienced the same problem on Linux: https://www.spinics.net/lists/pjsip/msg20517.html